# Selectively ignore certain api's for documentation

Tags: java, rest, wsdl, javadoc, enunciate

Does enunciate provide a means to selectively ignore certain api's?  For example, if I have the following REST service:

```
@PUT
@Path("/somePath")
@Produces({"application/xml"})
Response somePrivateService(Data someData);
```

How can I exclude it from the documentation enunciate generates?  For example:

```
@PUT
@Path("/somePath")
@Produces({"application/xml"})
@IgnoreThisEnunciate
Response somePrivateService(Data someData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that at the method-level. I've logged a JIRA issue for you, though:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-541